# Location of Java Shared objects on Mac machine?

Tags: java, macos, shared-libraries

If my installation calls for:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/client`

For unix machines... what is the equivalant for Mac machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which libraries you need, it's a bit hard to say. Some of the libraries are stored in `/usr/lib/java` (at least on Snow Leopard). For the variable to use, you should check out [`man dyld`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html). For basic `dylib` loading, use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.